# How to assign a value to one of an object's properties if the property name is not known until runtime

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I don't know which property of my object needs to be assigned until runtime.

The class instance is `servicerecord` and it has several properties defined as string:

```
public class ServiceRecord
 {
      public ServiceRecord(){}

       public string dos1 { get; set; }
       public string dos2 { get; set; }
       public string dos3 { get; set; }
       public string dos4 { get; set; }
       <snip>
  }
```

Let's say that at runtime, I discover that the program needs to assign a string value, say "11/2/2016" (i.e. the string representation of a date) to `servicerecord.dos3`.

How is that done using System.Reflection in C#?

In javascript it would be:  `servicerecord["dos3"] = ...`

What's the C# counterpart to referring to a property by a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [PropertyInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) to do this.

```
// Get property to write to.
PropertyInfo pi = _serviceRecord.GetType().GetProperty("dos3");
// Write value to property.
pi.SetValue(_serviceRecord, stringValue, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you'd want a `Dictionary<string,string>`. Remember to initialise your four entries in ServiceRecord's constructor